# Reloading code onto raspberry pi 3 and running it

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3

I am currently writing a program that detects if an IoT is compromised (i.e sending information its not supposed to). When this behaviour is detected by the control server, it will then get the device to reset by downloading its uncompromised code functions (which i have on a cloud) and running them. Is there a way to do this. Im using nodejs on my raspberry by the way.

Is there a way to shutdown or reboot a raspberry pi via a script?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hi, the question is wethere there is a way to remotely reset a raspberry pi or shut it down by using a script?

Answer (score 0):

You can issue the command:

`ssh <user>@<ip address to Pi> 'echo <password> | sudo <full path to shutdown command> -r now'`

Replace  with the Pi's username, replace  with the password, and that path to shutdown (which you can find while connected to the Pi do `which shutdown`). And fill in the IP address to your PI.

That should reboot your Pi.